# getting all data with search form if user didn't insert some fields in cake php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to update my function which is searching for data filtered by a *start date - end date*.

I want that function to get the all related search if the user didn't insert any date. How can I do that?

Here is my function :

```
$conditions = $this->CustodyKeys->find()
         ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
               return $exp->between('CustodyKeys.received_date',
                   $this>request->query['received_date_from'], 
                   $this->request->query['received_date_to']);
           })
          ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
               return $exp->between('CustodyKeys.return_date', 
                   $this->request->query['return_date_from'],
                   $this->request->query['return_date_to']);
           })     
         ->contain('HoldersKeys')
         ->contain('KeysManagement.DoorsManagement')
         ->contain('KeysCustodyType')
         ->contain('KeysCustodyStatus')
         ->where(['KeysCustodyType.id' =>1])
         ->where(['KeysCustodyStatus.id'=> 
               $this->request->query['keys_custody_status_name']])
```

Comment: Test the input fields and amend the query accordingly if no dates are entered

Comment: Do you mean i do double function and if the user didn't insert any data then use the second function ?

Comment: Not exactly, test dates before this query, then if dates are empty, dont add the date selection into the qurey